# how to put overlay icon inside a textbox/textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a textarea and I want to allow the user to click on it, and on click I would like to show them a form.

On click and show form can be easily done with jquery as per my knowledge of UI development. 
But how to put a icon inside the textbox/textarea? Something like this

[image]

I tried to search for demos of this but could not find any.

Comment: people uses `margin-bottom` or `position:relative` + `bottom: -10px` to do this

Comment: Do you want to share what you've tried so far?

Comment: @theMarceloR Yes of-course ! http://jsfiddle.net/WTpPH/2/

Comment: @user2173803 Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Au5L2/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here

```
<textarea row=100 cols=60></textarea>
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-1-n" id="arrow"></span>
```

CSS

```
#arrow{
    margin-left:-20px;
    position:relative;
}
textarea{
    float:left;
}
```

See it in action
http://jsfiddle.net/N99Vs/

Comment: Great! how did you do that,  i feel css dirty programming language but very usefull.  Can you do for a textbox also similarly ?

Comment: I suggest you read up on css and html tags. Its same thing, only switched textarea to input. http://jsfiddle.net/N99Vs/1/
Its hard to get hang on to at first, but gets easier with more practice

Comment: Thank you , i will give a try for reading. But actually i do not enjoy programming css,js,jquery

Answer (score -1):

There you go, I have updated the jsfiddle for you.
http://jsfiddle.net/WTpPH/115/
Basically

**html**

```
<div>
<textarea></textarea>
<a href='#'>c</a>
</div>
```

**css**

```
div { position:relative; width: 200px; }
textarea { display: inline-block; width: 100%; height: 200px }
a{
    background-color:red;
    position: absolute;
    right: 2px;
    bottom: 8px;
}
textarea + a {
    display: none;
}
textarea:hover + a {
    display: block;
}
textarea + a:hover {
    display: block;
}
```